# Assign Element of Array to Variable Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to assign the element of an array to a variable so I can use it later. For example:

```
constraints=("A" "B" "C" "E" "Q" "P" "S")

constraint=A

... a loop ...

rand=$[$RANDOM % ${#constraints[@]}]

let constraint="${constraints[${rand}]}"

echo $constraint

... end of loop ...
```

If the array is all numeric values, it works. But if they are strings the echo always outputs 0. Why?

Comment: I suggest to remove `let`.

Comment: Yup. `let` makes your operation arithmetic. All the strings `A`, `B`, `C`, `E`, `Q`, `P` and `S` evaluate to arithmetic 0.

Comment: BTW, `$[ ... ]` is 1970s-era math syntax; on modern (post-1991-POSIX-sh) shells, use `$(( ))` instead of either that *or* `let`.

Comment: As another aside -- it's unusual for this to matter (`$RANDOM` isn't the typical choice if you're deciding a lottery or generating keys to encrypt military secrets, after all), but if `${#constraints[@]}` doesn't divide evenly into 32768, then the "random" choice being made here isn't quite fairly weighted. If in a case where this matters, you'll want to compare the randomly-chosen value to see if it's greater than `$(( 32768 - (32768 % ${#constraints[@]}) ))` and pick a different random number until that isn't true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` is only for arithmetic operations. Your strings have no numeric value (unless they name variables which themselves have numeric values), so they all evaluate to `0` in that context.

Make it:

```
constraint="${constraints[${rand}]}"
```

...with no `let`.

---

In context, this might look like:

```
constraints=(A B C E Q P S)
rand=$(( RANDOM % ${#constraints[@]} ))
constraint=${constraints[${rand}]}
echo "$constraint"
```

Note:

- See [the bash-hackers' wiki page on obsolete syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) for discussion of `$[ ]` and `let`. Neither is good form in modern scripting.
- Quotes are not needed (though it's safe to use them, and good practice to do so whenever unsure!) on items that parse unambiguously to a single word during an assignment, as both string-splitting and glob expansion are turned off by default in this context.
- Quotes *are* needed for `echo $var` if the values themselves, or the value of the IFS variable, are unknown or not controlled. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the "let."

```
constraints=("A" "B" "C" "E" "Q" "P" "S")
constraint=A
rand=$[$RANDOM % ${#constraints[@]}]
constraint="${constraints[${rand}]}"
echo $constraint
```

Comment: If you're going to duplicate the entirety of the code, you might want to clean up the other bad practices (missing quotes, use of deprecated `$[ ]` syntax, etc).